# Replace all occurrences of multiple curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a situation where there will be multiple instances where strings contain `{{}}` or `{{{}}}` or more combinations of curly brackets.

I'm using this currently `string.replace(/\{\{/g , '').replace(/\}\}/g , '')` but this only removes strings with double brackets. I need a regex to be able to replace all occurrences of two or more enclosed curly brackets and to remove them and everything in between.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean like `{{2,}|}{2,}` https://regex101.com/r/5ZMv6j/1

Comment: Should/can the regex match on {{something}}}, i.e. an unbalanced amount of brackets?

Comment: No just balanced amount of brackets please.

Comment: @Thefourthbird do I need to add escape \ slashes between the brackets for use in javascript?

Comment: I don't think so, but this does not take balances curly braces into account, just 2 or more.

Comment: Okay no problem, it's working now. Can you please set that as the answer? :)

Comment: @user2028856 I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 1 replace statement using an alternation `|` which matches either 2 or more times an opening curly brace `{{2,}` or 2 or more times a closing curly brace `}{2,}`

```
{{2,}|}{2,}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ZMv6j/1)

```js
[
  "{{{{{test1}}}}}}}}{}",
  "{{{{{test2}}}}}}}}",
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(/{{2,}|}{2,}/g, '')))
```

Answer (score 1):

So this

```
'aaa {{bb}} ccc {ddd} eee {{{ffff}}}'.replace(/\{{2,}/g, '{').replace(/\}{2,}/g, '}');
```

gives me the following string: `"aaa {bb} ccc {ddd} eee {ffff}"`.

I hope this helps